# Remove/delete Firebase dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created the dynamic links using Firebase console. But there are no option to remove or delete or edit options.

I want to delete dynamic links from the console. Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.

Deleting links would be a problem since that could lead to broken data and user experiences. At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), we don't allow link deletion either (you can 'Archive' the link to get it off the screen, but that does not make the URL inactive).

Firebase probably prevents editing for the same reason. At Branch, we do allow editing of everything except the link URL (since that would be effectively deleting the link).

Comment: But what if I just created it and want to delete it right away?! Common! :(

Comment: @user2520215 I totally understand your point — it comes down to infrastructure on the backend, where disappearing links would cause havoc! It would require a lot of work for something most people wouldn't use. Try the Archive option, or just forget that the link ever existed

Comment: Yep, I just tried it for a prototype, found something better and just don't need the deep link. Please let me delete it!
There are many more usecases than the one where links are already used in production.

Answer (score 5):

Google just added the edit and archive feature. You can check that out in the Firebase console

Answer (score 0):

You can only archive the link but the link will still work, but it will no longer be displayed on the Firebase console.

[image]

If you desperately wanted to delete it, what you can do is delete the URL prefix and associated links; all dynamic links and analytics associated with that domain are permanently deleted.